# Poi slide formatting

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a PPT presentation with apache POI  and I ould like to add Title for the PPT with the below code. But it throws compilation error as

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

      //creating presentation
      XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();            

      //getting the slide master object
      XSLFSlideMaster slideMaster = ppt.getSlideMasters()[0];

      //get the desired slide layout 
      XSLFSlideLayout titleLayout = slideMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE);

      //creating a slide with title layout
      XSLFSlide slide1 = ppt.createSlide(titleLayout);

      //selecting the place holder in it 
      XSLFTextShape title1 = slide1.getPlaceholder(0);
```

Comment: Which line is it objecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `ppt.getSlideMasters()` returns `List<XSLFSlideMaster>` instead of `XSLFSlideMaster[]` as you're expecting.
So, for the problem you want to solve the following code should be OK:

```
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Slideshow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //creating presentation
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.ppt");
             XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();) {
            //getting the slide master object
            XSLFSlideMaster slideMaster = ppt.getSlideMasters().get(0);

            //get the desired slide layout
            XSLFSlideLayout titleLayout = slideMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE);

            //creating a slide with title layout
            XSLFSlide slide1 = ppt.createSlide(titleLayout);

            //selecting the place holder in it
            XSLFTextShape title1 = slide1.getPlaceholder(0);
            title1.setText("Text title");
            ppt.write(out);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result will be:
[image]